# How to create RTK-Query endpoint as empty with typescript when using inject endpoints

Tags: typescript, redux, rtk-query

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: ()={}, ==> it throws as error Typescript safety is not met
});
```

Please provide any help, how can I add Typescript safety.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { EndpointDefinitions } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query';


export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (): EndpointDefinitions => ({} as EndpointDefinitions), // <=== note here
});
```

This can be fixed by casting the rtk query endpoints type.

Comment: Doesn't even need the cast (and you should not do that!). You just need the `()` around the `{}`. WIthout it, it's a method body without a return statement. With it, it's returning an empty object,